Problem with pages numbers in knowledgeArticle via REST API
I am creating a pagination of the knowledgeArticle object. after query execution:
/services/data/v52.0/query/?q=select+count()+from+knowledgeArticle

I receive the quantity:
totalSize: 1349

Then I create pagination using URL:
/services/data/v60.0/support/knowledgeArticles?pageNumber=1&pageSize100

And here the problem begins because I can only go to page 6, which gives me visibility of 600 records. The number of records where FirstPublishedDate != null is 1146.
The question is - why can I only see 600 records?
